# AdMob banner not displayed Phonegap + JqueryMobile

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to use admob in my apps, but if i add a new campaign in adMob administration (I selected smartphone web) and add generated code to my app banner, the ad is not shown.

I checked, that I have allowed prermission in AndroidManifest.xml and looks it O.K.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML i define a RelativeLayout with the id banner_admob then I start the banner from Java code.

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_admob);
AdView banner = new AdView(mActivity, AdSize.BANNER, "banner");
banner.loadAd(new AdRequest());
root.addView(banner);
```

Comment: In res/layout/main.xml or where?

Comment: Yes, if that is what your activity or fragment use.